# Power steering works normally to one side, but hard to the other

Tags: ford, power-steering

My Ford Mondeo was leaking from the steering rack. So it was repaired by a steering specialist. After about 1,000 kms it steers smoothly to right but when turning towards the left it feels like there is no power assist.

Comment: Start your car.. Let it get to normal temp.... Check steering fluid... If full (hot level)... Then turn steering all the way right just before it maxs ( don't max it out!) ... Do the same but to the left.... Repeat... Check fluid again... Any change?

Comment: You may have air and need to bleed ... Or perhaps low fluid...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible when he repaired it he didn't Jack it up and adjust a steering that's so you got right and left equal pressure possible one way and not the other you check the steering nut on the steering box to make sure it's a it's right if your steering column Center when your wheels are straight

Answer (score 0):

Take it back and have them check it out. Maybe the inner seal is leaking on that side of the rack, slightly, causing pressure loss. It seems odd that it would not be hard to turn in both directions, however the other possibility is that if the steering rack has worn teeth. This will effect a portion of the steering (that has the bad teeth), but not all of it.. Strange..

If you didn't want to run back to your specialist just yet, check the power steering fluid resivour, use only approved FoMoCo fluid, and top off a low level as you rotate your steering wheel from hard left to hard right, at idle.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a problem like this before. If it does have the 2 banjo bolts on the steering rack, 1 of them will have a little ball valve inside which can get stuck. it is normally very easy to check it by just removing it and testing the little ball on the inside. Also much cheap repair.